# How to get right encoding for string

Tags: c#, encoding

I have these two string :

```
Ankara Esenbo\u011fa Havaliman\u0131
Ankara Esenboğa Havalimanı
```

What encoding do i apply so the second one becomes the first one?

Comment: I don't think you need an encoding, but a function, here...

Comment: @RichouHunter you mean like manually listing all the charaters?

Comment: If you want the second one to become the first one, you have to specify what characters it is that you want to turn into escape codes. I could write code to convert those two specific characters, but that is not what I think that you need.

Comment: Just checked the linked dupe against your input... Works a treat.